# Cannot write image to a directory on my website

Tags: jsp

Im trying to write a file to my server.  I set all permissions on the folder to allow me to write files to a specific directory, however I'm getting the following error when trying to save an image to the directory.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: access denied 
           (java.io.FilePermission {MyDirectory/myImage.png delete)
```

Now, I have permission to read/write/execute to the folder, I am not trying to delete the file, however I see "delete" listed in the issue above.

I'm using a shared hosting solution, but I set the permissions on the directory to allow me to write to it, so I'm not sure what the issue is.  Here is the line of code that is giving me the problem.

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "PNG", filOutput);
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Does the *server* have write permissions?  `chmod 777` it temporarily and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, the folder currently has 777 assigned to it

Answer (score 1):

JasperReports may be running as a different user than Apache.  So ensure that your 
JasperReports user has the correct permissions to read/write files to that particular directory.

Even try doing it manually from the command line to verify the correct permissions for the JasperReports user.

Comment: Im actually unable to run it via the command line due to being on a shared host...